# Drupal commerce cart not working after upgrading from kickstart-7.x-2.9 to 7.x-2.20

Tags: 7, commerce, upgrading

I have a site using the commerce_kickstart-7.x-2.9 install profile (Drupal 7.22). Updating the site was long overdue, so being cautious I decided to do the update on a new server with a domain name I bought just for testing. I put extracted the up to date copy of kickstart commerce (kickstart-7.x-2.20) on to the server. Then I added in my modules and themes into sites/all. I needed to uninstall the securepages module as it was forcing the login page to go back to the old site.

The core upgrade seemed to go fine. I could see my site working. However I could not add items to the cart. The Item added successfully dialogue box shows, but nothing is actually added to the cart. I updated all of my contributed modules to see if this might help, but it didn't.

The new copy of the site does not have an SSL certificate yet, so I will either need to move the SSL certificate or apply the updates on the live copy of the site. However I am very keen to get to the bottom of why items can no longer be added to the cart before I apply any changes to the live site.

Why has my cart stopped working after the upgrade and what can I do to fix it? Any help would be appreciated. Please let me know if there are any troubleshooting steps I can take to provide further information.

Comment: This is just a comment - I used Kickstart to learn Drupal Commerce but I eventually dropped Kickstart in all my sites and decided to install Drupal Commerce as individual modules. The reason for that is I got into the same problem that you have after upgrading Kickstart. In all probability your DB is not in sync with the modules  which are not upgraded one by one but copied whole in the manner that you upgrade the Drupal Core.   ..... I suggest you get help from the Kickstart guys since you have a prod site.

Comment: Thanks Paulo. I posted with Kickstart originally but haven't heard anything yet, hence my post here. If I don't have any luck, would abandoning Kickstart help me here? I guess I would just roll back to before the kickstart update and update the drupal core and then the commerce modules separately. Are there any other things I should do moving away from Kickstart?

Comment: That may work, in my case I built a site from ground up, - I believe I tried that route but at some point in time I lost the ability to update the modules got fed up (If I remember correctly a DB update script did not go well wreaking my test site), created a new install of drupal and installed the modules one by one.

Comment: BTW Kickstart do not follow the usual Drupal folder structure (sites/all/modules) - cannot remember if I hit issues because of that.